# Is this a Trig Identity?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm new to trig identities, and Ive come across this part of a question.  Can someone tell me if the next part equation comes from a trig identity. 
[image]

Thanks
Mike

Comment: What are $g,S$ ?

Comment: Please don’t include critical parts of your question as an image. It’s neither searchable nor accessible to people using screen readers.

Answer (score 2):

It is basically :
$$\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}=\tan(x)$$

Comment: Thank you that helped, i didnt think to split the terms

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on the third term, $\dfrac{S\cos{50}\sin{25}}{\cos{25}}$, we can rewrite it as 
$$S\cos{50}\cdot\dfrac{\sin{25}}{\cos{25}}$$

As user35508 said, $$\dfrac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}=\tan(x)$$ so we can rewrite $S\cos{50}\cdot\dfrac{\sin{25}}{\cos{25}}$ as $$S\cos{50}\tan{25}$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the trig identity of sin(x)/cos(x) = tan(x)